# Finding specific JSON array values when no keys are specified

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I'm accessing a JSON array that looks like this:

```
{"female":[
  [1,17,99,22],
  [3,24,13,26],
  [7,54,11,27]
],"male":[
  [1,18,75,33],
  [3,15,44,47],
  [7,27,86,55]
]}
```

On the frontend, the user selects the gender and a value that corresponds with the first value in the array string. Based on those inputs, I want to look at the JSON and display one of the corresponding values.

For example, user select "male" and "3 years old". The first value in each row of the array is age. The value I'm interested in finding is in the 3rd position in the row array. So in this case, I'd want to find "44".

I think I could built this if there were keys, but I'm stumped on how to match just based on position.

EDIT:

Let me explain a little better. User inputs two variables into a form, the first is gender. The second is, let's say age in years, which corresponds with the first column. I want to display a value that I already know corresponds with the 3rd column (in this case let's say it's "Expected BMI"). So I want to display an Expected BMI of 44 if the user chooses "male" and "3 years old".

Another example, if the users selects a "female" and "7 years old", it should output 11.

Comment: how do you decide that it's 44 and not 75 or 86?

Comment: `"male" and "3" and I want to find the output "44"` - Is the 3rd value in 2nd row.. How do you know to pick from 2nd row.

Comment: Added a longer explanation to the question. This is just the initial example -- other values in the row would be displayed based on different form inputs.

Comment: your explanation still doesn't make sense lol. How do you connect the number `3` to `44`? Based on the data you provided, what would be the BMI of a 3 year old female?

Comment: More specifically, what do the sets of arrays represent? age or BMI? or something else?

Comment: I'm using completely random numbers but the arrays are average for various health statistics sorted by gender and then by age (in the first column). So in this example, the average BMI for a 3 year-old male would be output as 44. The other columns represent standard deviation, etc. And yes, these are completely fictional numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that 3 means what i think it does (value of the 1st element in the row under gender to select) and you just forgot to mention the other 3 valued variable meaning column index. Then this may solve most of your problem:

[jsfiddle available](http://jsfiddle.net/theredhead/WKrWu/)

```
function getSomeNumberByGenderAndAgeAtColumn(gender, age, col) {
    // get the real data by some means?
    var vals = {"female":[
      [1,17,99,22],
      [3,24,13,26],
      [7,54,11,27]
    ],"male":[
      [1,18,75,33],
      [3,15,44,47],
      [7,27,86,55]
    ]};

    // small private helper
    var findRowByAge = 
        function(arr, age) {
            var line = null;
            for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
                if (arr[i][0] == age) {
                    line = arr[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
            return line;
        }
    var line = findRowByAge(vals[gender], age);
    return line != null ? line[col-1] : 'N.A.';
}

// should be 44
$('#result').text(getSomeNumberByGenderAndAgeAtColumn('male', 3, 3));
```

Comment: Excellent, this is exactly what I needed. And yes, sorry for the confusion with threes and column indexes. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this work for you?

```
var gender = 'male';
var age = 3;

var resultNumber = jsonData[0][gender].filter(function(i) {
  if (i[0] == age) {
    return true;
  }
})[0][2];
```

In this case `resultNumber` will be 44.

Let me know if this is *not* what you want.

Comment: This seems to be the right idea, but I'm getting erros: http://jsfiddle.net/mark47/EBrzA/

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy. Remember the usage of 2 D arrays, well, we are gonna use them.

The code will look like this :

```
var json = [
{
"male" : [
  [1,18,75,33],
  [3,15,44,47],
  [7,27,86,55]
]
}];

for (var key in json) {
if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
  if(json[key].male[1][0] == 3)
        alert("Result is ::"+json[key].male[1][2])
}
}
```

Run this fiddle to find the working solution : http://jsfiddle.net/Jpd9W/

Comment: I don't know which row in the json to look at until the user inputs the age. This solution seems to have hard-coded the row `male[1]` -- this might be in part due to my poor explanation.